# Proof of surjectivity of a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, solution-verification

I have to prove that:
$$p(x)=x^5+5x^2+5x+1$$
is surjective.
My idea:
$1)$ $\lim_{x\to\infty}p(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}p(x)=-\infty$.
$2)$ $p(x)$ is continuous.

> $Goal:$ $\forall y\in \mathbb{R}\, \exists x\in\mathbb{R}: \, f(x)=y.$

From the limits I know that $\forall M>0 \exists H>0: \forall \,x>H$ then $f(x)>M$ 
and $\forall M>0$ $\exists\, H>0$: $\forall\, x<-H$ then $f(x)<-M$.
So I can take $x_1>H$ and $x_2<-H$ and so $f(x_1)>|y|$ and $f(x_2)<-|y|$, where $|y|=M$. This means that surely:
$$f(x_1)<y<f(x_2)\,\,\,\, (*)$$
So let $g(x):=f(x)-y$ then $\exists x\in(x_1,x_2)$ such that $g(x)=0$
and so $f(x)=y$.

**All my steps are right?** (In particular I am not convinced I can say (*))

Comment: I think in some places you are confusing H and M. And basically, you want to apply the intermediate value theorem, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the idea.

We know that

- $\forall M \ge 0, \exists H>0: \forall x > H \implies f(x) > M$.
- $\forall M \ge 0, \exists H>0: \forall x < -H \implies f(x) < -M$.

We can choose $H_1>0$ such that if $x> H_1$ then $f(x) > |y|$. Let $x_1 >H_1$.

We can choose $H_2>0$ such that if $x<-H_2$ then $f(x)<-|y|$. We choose $x_2<-H_2$.

Then we have

$$f(x_2)<-|y| \le y \le |y| < f(x_1)$$

Since $p$ being a polynomial is continuous, by [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), since $y \in $[f(x_2), f(x_1)] we conclude that we can find $x\in [x_2, x_1]$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: so do you mean my idea is correct but can I conclude directly the proof with the intermediate value theorem without using the theorem of zeros? I believe my idea is a sort of proof of the intermediate value theorem applied in this case, right?

Comment: we do not have to shift it to zero, unless you have not learned about the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Only a thing: the intermediate value theorem states that $\forall y_0\in [f(a), f(b)]\, \exists x_0\in[a,b]:f(x_0)=f(y_0)$, but in my case I have strict inequality (I mean the extremes of the intervals are not included)...how can I solve this?

Comment: We can conclude that $y \in [f(x_2), f(x_1)]$ right?

Comment: Why can I include the extremes?? Anyway in the theorem the extremes must be included?

Comment: this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/938132/306553) is of interest to you.  Note that we have proven that $f(x_2) \le y \le f(x_1)$.  Also note that if $a<b$, then we have $a \le b$.

Comment: Oh yes I agree, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is sound but your details are a little confusing. This is easier. You know that $p$ can be arbitrarily large or small so, given $r\in R$ choose $a$ so that $p(a)\lt r$ and choose $b$ so that $p(b)\gt r$. The Intermediate Value theorem assures that $p$ takes all values between $p(a)$ and $p(b)$ so there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $p(c)=r$. Since this is true for all $r$, $p$ is surjective.