# Generalized Mean Value Theorem + Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, mean-value-theorem

Assume $f: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function on the closed interval $[a,b]$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and that $f$ is differentiable on its domain.

Then by the Mean Value Theorem it holds true that:
$$f(c + d) = f(c) + d \times f'(e)$$Where $e \in (c, c+d)$. Now assume $f: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function on the closed interval $[a,b]$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and that $f$ has left and right derivative everywhere, where the two need not be equal and one of them may be $\pm \infty$.

Then the following inequality holds true:
$$
f(c + d) \geq f(c) + d \times \min\{f'(e-), f'(e+)\}
$$

Where again $e \in (c, c+d)$. I understand that by the generalization of the IVT to the case where continuity is guaranteed on an open interval (see for instance this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938121/does-intermediate-value-theorem-apply-to-continuity-on-open-intervals) for more details) we have $\min\{f'(e-), f'(e+)\}$ in this case instead of $f'(e)$ above, but where does the inequality come from?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You should give a reference. In particular, many here probably do not know what you mean by "**the** generalization of the IVT", especially since there are many generalizations of IVT. That said, perhaps these papers by Dwight Benjamin Goodner will be of use: [*Mean value theorems for functions with finite derivates*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2309443) (1960) AND [*An extension of a theorem of Darboux*](https://www.e-periodica.ch/cntmng?pid=ens-001%3A1961%3A7%3A%3A70) (1961) AND [*An extended mean value theorem*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2688126) (1963). **(continued)**

Comment: See also [*Mean-value theorems for one-sided differentiable functions*](http://yadda.icm.edu.pl/baztech/element/bwmeta1.element.baztech-c631b866-394e-4f11-9f73-ba5bc4e75c31) by Wituła/Hetmaniok/Słota (2012).